# Update custom fields value in magento cart

Tags: php, magento

Need to update custom field value in magento order where `order_date` is my custom field.

```
$order2 = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(100000013);
```

It returns following exception Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object.

Any solution for fix this issue ?

Comment: $order2->setData('order_date', "2014-12-12");
$order2->save();
I have tried this but it is giving me Error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object.

Answer (score 1):

Your order not able to load by magento that's why magento giving you error.

you are passing order increment id in the load function

**Load By Increment Id**

```
$id = 100000013;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($id); 
$order->setData('order_date', "2014-12-12");
$order->save();
```

**Load By Order Id(Entity Id)**

```
$id = 13;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id); 
$order->setData('order_date', "2014-12-12");
$order->save();
```

Please check.

Comment: Yes, it is working for single field. How can I use this for multiple fields.
Like : $arrayVal = array("order_date"=>"2014-07-07", "mobile_number"=>"123123123");

Comment: $arrayVal = array("order_date"=>"2014-07-07", "mobile_number"=>"123123123");
$order2->addData($arrayVal);
$order2->save();

It works for me. Thanks.